# ASP.NET MVC 3 Unobtrusive client side Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a reference available of the html validation attributes for cases where we want to use unobtrusive client side validation without using Data Annotations?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We unfortunately had to do this recently, since only the view was under our control. Since the unobtrusive validation is really meant to be used in conjunction with data annotations, you probably won't find documentation online for how to use them separately.

We found that the easiest thing to do was to create a spike project, and add the correct data annotations to some test model, create a simple "EditorFor" view for it, look at the generated HTML, and copy over the data attributes that ASP.NET MVC added to the text boxes.

Comment: Chris, yes we ended up doing the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will find a reference for this but if you are not going to use Data Annotations I would simply recommend you hooking up the [jquery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) manually.